# A 3D polygon with sides tangent to a sphere

Tags: geometry

Imagine the quadrilateral in the picture placed on a sphere of size that allow the four sides to touch the sphere, in other words: the four sides of this 3D polygon are tangent to the sphere. The 4 points where the sides touch the sphere are on a circle. This has been presented here.

My question is: Are always the tangent points of any n side polygon on a circle?

[image]

Comment: Suppose you construct a 6-sided polygon one vertex at a time, i.e. pick point A arbitrarily, pick any point B such that AB is tangent to the sphere, pick C so that BC is tangent, and so on. Choosing vertices A through E gives you four tangent points that certainly need not lie on a circle. Can you always pick vertex F such that both EF and FA are tangent to the sphere? (Hint: yes.)

Comment: I see your point and I agree that this proves the point that not all cases are such. I wonder if there is a condition that will imply that all tangent points on a circle.

Comment: If the polygon is planar, the all tangent points lie on a circle (intersection between the sphere and the plane holding the polygon).

Comment: @achille You are right. What is interesting that for the case of a quadrilateral, even if the polygon is not planar, the 4 touching points of the tangent segments still lie on a planar (circle). I was wondering if there  are more cases such as this and under what conditions.